# Modify ValueType from extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

A few days ago I needed to toggle a `bool`, and I ended up doing like so:

```
IsVisible = !IsVisible;
```

I found that to be the simplest way to archive that functionality. But before doing like the example above, I tried out some different ways.

Mostly about using a extension method. Which in my opinion would make it even simpler, or at least less chars to write.

```
IsVisible.toggle();
```

But as a `boolean` is a value type, the `bool` that is sent though to the extension method is a copy of the original `bool`, and not a reference type.

```
public static void Toggle(this boolean value)
{
    value = !value;
}
```

Which would do what I needed, but as the `boolean` getting toggled is a copy of the original `boolean` the change isn't applied to the original...

I tried putting the ref keyword in front of `boolean`, but that didn't compile.
And I still haven't found a reason for that not compiling, wouldn't that be the perfect functionality for extension methods?

```
public static void Toggle(this ref boolean value)
```

I even tried casting the `boolean` into a object, which in my head would make it into a reference type, and then it would no longer be a copy and the change would get passed back. That didn't work either.

So my question is if it's possible to make a extension pass back changes, or another way to make it even simpler than it already is?

I know it quite possible won't get any simpler or more logical than the top example, but you never know :)

Comment: Make it as simple as possible, but no simpler. -Einstein

Comment: btw, extension methods must be static. I guess they are in you code, you just forgot to make them static here

Comment: Don't overlook that your `Toggle()` extension method would add meaning and context to your code— making your code more readable and implicitly documented.  Not every boolean-not operation is meant to be a toggle.

Comment: NOTE: As of C# 7.2, this is allowed with `this ref` extension methods for value types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Primitive types are immutable.  You'll have to write your calling code like this:

```
IsVisible = IsVisible.Toggle();
```

That's the best you can do with extension methods.  No way around it.

Comment: maybe IsVisible = Boolean.Toggle() ?

Comment: No - how would "Boolean" as a type know about the state contained the "IsVisible" instance? The right-hand expression _must_ include the variable somewhere.

Comment: structs are value types but unfortunately they are not immutable by default.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: The existence of methods which mutate `this` is a separate question from whether a struct is mutable.  Saying `Struct1=Struct2;` will, if Struct1 is a mutable storage location, mutate Struct1 by overwriting Struct1's fields with corresponding values in Struct2; nothing in the declaration of the structure type can change that behavior.  The only really problematic "default" behavior is one which C# offers no control over: assuming `readOnlyStruct.Method()` may be replaced with `var temp=readOnlyStruct; temp.Method();`, without allowing `Method` to say whether that's safe.

Comment: @supercat Yes, an `immutating` (or similar) keyword for methods would be nice, like C++'s function-`const`.

Answer (score 1):

as an aside: wouldn't an extension method be an incredible overhead for something as simple as toggling a bool?

Comment: Yes it would.  It's not encapsulating a combination of steps, it's leading you to avoid using a built-in operator.  I try to stick with idiomatically sensible code and do my best to avoid writing DSLs (until it makes sense to).

Comment: It's a terrible example, and the code sample was in fact the code that made me curious. Yeah, no excuse.

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net, extension methods may be declared to accept the implied "this" as a `ByRef` parameter (equivalent to `ref` in C#).  Such methods work about as one would expect, but for the unfortunate fact that invoking such an extension method on something other than a mutable storage location (e.g. on a property value, readonly storage location, etc.) will cause the compiler silently pass reference to a copy of the parameter, rather than issuing a compilation error [silly behavior, given that 90% of the time the whole *point* of using a `ref` parameter would be to be able to modify it at the call site].  Unfortunately, while C# is generally capable of using extension methods written in vb, it won't allow `ref` parameters to be passed without the `ref` keyword, and it provides no legal way of specifying `ref` except when using static-function-call syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 7.2, extension methods can have a mutable "this" reference, as long as the parameter is a value type. See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#refin-extension-methods